# Vue array to django

Tags: django, vue.js, django-views

Im having a lot of issues on this and couldn't find a solution, im using Django and vue.js I have created a form which allows me to add multiple inputs on a certain click, this part works fine. However what I want to do on submit is add these inputs in my django view to my models.
My model set up is a one to one for my title and then a one to many for my paragraph and my header.
My hope was to simply loop through all my inputs check what 'type'(title, para or header) it is and then assign to the correct model.
Any help or guidance on how to do this is much appreciated, below is the code I have so far

HTML

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}

<form  method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="con">
      <button type="button" name="button" @click='addHead()'>
          header
      </button>
      <button type="button" name="button" @click='addPara()'>
          Para
      </button>
        <div id="body-fields">
          <div class="car-body" v-for="(post, index) in posts">
            {% verbatim %}
            <input style='display:none'name = 'count' v-bind:value='[index]' >
             {% endverbatim %}
            <input type="textbox" v-bind:name='[post.type]' v-model='post.content'>
            <span style="float:right;background-color:green" @click='removeForm(index)'>
                x
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" vaule="save"/>
      </div>
</form>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'blog/JS/main.js'%}" type="text/javascript"></script>

  {% endblock content %}
```

Vue.js

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '.con',
    data:{
      posts: [
      {
        content:'',
        type:'title'
      }
    ],
    },
    methods:{
      addHead(index){
        this.posts.push({
          content:'',
          type:'header',
        })
      },
      addPara(index){
        this.posts.push({
          content:'',
          type:'para',
        })
      },
      removeForm(){
        this.posts.splice(index, 1)
      }
    }
})
```

Comment: didn't you post the same question some days ago? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60536343/vue-js-array-into-django

Comment: You can not use Django Forms to 'submit' Vue.js values to Django Views. You are basically mixing 2 different techniques.
If you want to use Vue.js with Ajax posts to submit Vue.js data to the backend  (Django), you need a way in your backend to receive these posts.  See below for DRF link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using Django with a Javascript framework, the best approach is via Django Rest Framework imho.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/